# Retreat Into Isolation/Isolationism

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the correct preposition to use with "***isolationism***" and "***isolation***".  On the web, I found examples along the lines of:

> 1. The country retreated ***into isolation***.
> 2. The country retreated ***into isolationism***.

Isolation is the state of being alone.  Isolationism is the idea or policy of a country not having relations with other countries.

The phrase "*retreat into isolation*" seems normal to me, because a country could be "*in isolation*", and so it could definitely "*retreat into isolation*."  But, "*retreat into isolationism*" seems off to me, because a country could not be "*in isolationism*".

What do native speaker think?  Is "*retreat into isolationism*" in sentence 2 wrong?

Comment: 'Retreated  into isolationism' sounds more idiomatic to me than 'retreated into isolation'. (AmE speaker)

Comment: You could certainly retreat into isolationism - it's a state of mind, a philosophical position.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but have quite different meanings.

To retreat into isolation is to seek solace from one's difficulties or problems through solitude.

For example:

> We haven't seen Daniel in weeks. After his breakup with Sally he retreated into isolation.

To retreat into isolationism is something that a people or country might do, or be accused of doing, rather than enter into a conflict. It would not be a complementary thing to say. To retreat into isolationism would be the national equivalent of sticking one's fingers in one's ears and saying, "Lalalalala" in a futile attempt at ignoring something one does not wish to face.

It can also be used to describe an individual's actions. Where the first statement indicates that a person has gone somewhere to be alone, the second implies that a person is actively ignoring a problem, or avoiding a confrontation.

For example:

> Rather than addressing the nightly incursions of his neighbor's dog into his yard, the man elected to retreat into isolationism and built a very large fence.